# Use same instance of fragment in multiple activites

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have a non-UI persistant fragment to keep track of bluetooth devices in my app (so all pairings aren't lost as soon as the user turns the phone).

I now need to access the data in this fragment from several activites and other fragments. Suffice to say it's not an option to create a new instance of the fragment for each activity, it must be the same instance in all of them. Is this allowed or even possible? What would happen with the fragments' onDetach function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From google developers: "A fragment must always be embedded in an activity and the fragment's lifecycle is directly affected by the host activity's lifecycle. For example, when the activity is paused, so are all fragments in it, and when the activity is destroyed, so are all fragments."

Meaning it's not possible..

Comment: Well that is the case for a non-persistent fragment at least, but if it's persistant shouldn't a FragmentManager be able to find and refer to the fragment in multiple activites? But perhaps a persitent fragment isn't the best tool to use here, perhaps a service would be better.

Comment: See if this article helps: 
http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/android/6996-fragment-and-activity-working-together.html?start=4

Didn't understood your goal fully but isn't a simple Database an option?

Comment: Bluetooth connections can't just be stored in a database, they have to be kept alive. However I think a fragment was not a good choise, a service is probably what I should have used and with a service I don't get this problem as several activites can bind to it at the same time.